# Is DataSet supports complex type when GetXml method?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have the schema below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="WSParam">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="domain" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Cases">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="caseName" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I expected the output of DataSet.GetXml() below:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <WSParam>
        <domain>ad</domain>
        <userName>admin</userName>
        <Cases>
            <caseName>case 1</caseName>
        </Cases>
    </WSParam>
</NewDataSet>
```

But the output is:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <WSParam>
        <domain>ad</domain>
        <userName>admin</userName>
    </WSParam>
    <Cases>
        <caseName>case 1</caseName>
    </Cases>
</NewDataSet>
```

Anyone confirm me the correct behavior of DataSet.GetXml() with complex type or I miss something.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

**UPDATES1:**

I am using DataSet.ReadXmlSchema("...xsd"). From that, I use DataSet.Tables[..] to create DataTable to put the data. Then call DataSet.GetXml() to get the string XML representation.

**UPDATES2:**

**Code:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sXSD = @"C:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\XMLFile1.xsd";
    DataSet dsXSD = new DataSet();
    dsXSD.ReadXmlSchema(sXSD);
    int k = 0;
    do
    {
        DataRow d;
        d = dsXSD.Tables["tblUser"].NewRow();
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            d[i] = k;
            i = (i + 1);
        } while (i < dsXSD.Tables["tblUser"].Columns.Count);
        dsXSD.Tables["tblUser"].Rows.Add(d);
        d = dsXSD.Tables["tblUserRole"].NewRow();
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            d[i] = k;
            i = (i + 1);
        } while (i < dsXSD.Tables["tblUserRole"].Columns.Count);
        dsXSD.Tables["tblUserRole"].Rows.Add(d);
        k = (k + 1);
    } while (k < 3);
    dsXSD.WriteXml("c:\\test.xml");


}
```

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xsd:element name="tblUser">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="FullName" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="tblUserRole">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:int" />
              <xsd:element name="RoleID" type="xsd:int" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <tblUser>
    <UserID>0</UserID>
    <FullName>0</FullName>
    <tblUserRole>
      <UserID>0</UserID>
      <RoleID>0</RoleID>
    </tblUserRole>
  </tblUser>
  <tblUser>
    <UserID>1</UserID>
    <FullName>1</FullName>
    <tblUserRole>
      <UserID>1</UserID>
      <RoleID>1</RoleID>
    </tblUserRole>
  </tblUser>
  <tblUser>
    <UserID>2</UserID>
    <FullName>2</FullName>
    <tblUserRole>
      <UserID>2</UserID>
      <RoleID>2</RoleID>
    </tblUserRole>
  </tblUser>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: I would check your DataSet for DataRelation objects that connect WSParam and Cases.

Comment: I saw ChildRelations count to 1 named WSParam_Cases

Comment: I saw also DataSet.Relations. Seems correct.

Comment: As far as I know, your complexTypes are going to be their own tables.  You have some kind of relation between the two tables, most likely showing that Cases is a child of WSParam, but I have no clue how they would be mapped.

Comment: I saw a snippet over the net on how to generate structured xml based on the xsd. Allow me to update my post include it. The solution is very weird because I do the same but the different output. May I ask anybody to explain on how it works.

Comment: Would you mind to CHeCk tHe UPDATES2 beCause it is puzzle for me.

Comment: Anybody knows on how to get structured xml according to schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible using datasets.

But you could do it yourself by creating a non standard microsoft dataset xsd.
It requires a little work but you can afterwards tweak it as you like.

**The key is to use an xs:group.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="WSParam">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="domain" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:group ref="CasesGroup" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

    <xs:group name="CasesGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Cases">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CaseName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

For the above xsd (which I named wsparam.xsd) run "xsd.exe wsparam.xsd /classes /n:Yournamespace"

Now you can fill the data from code

```
    NewDataSetWSParam p = new NewDataSetWSParam();
    p.domain = "ad";
    p.userName = "admin";
    p.Cases = new NewDataSetWSParamCaseName[] {  
            new NewDataSetWSParamCaseName () { Value ="case 1" }
    };
```

Now comes the tricky part
Using a non standard XmlTextWriter when serializing to strip namespace attributes from the XML file

```
public class NoNamespaceXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
            public NoNamespaceXmlWriter(System.IO.TextWriter output)
                : base(output)
            {
                Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.None;
            }

            public override void WriteStartDocument() { }
            public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
            {
                base.WriteStartElement("", localName, "");
            }
        }
```

Use the code below to Serialize you object

```
string serialXML = string.Empty;
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        using (XmlWriter writer = new RDECommon.Xml.NoNamespaceXmlWriter(sw))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, p, ns);
            serialXML = sb.ToString();
        }
```

serialXML contains your xml

```
<NewDataSet>
    <WSParam>
        <domain>ad</domain>
        <userName>admin</userName>
        <Cases>
            <caseName>case 1</caseName>
        </Cases>
    </WSParam>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: This would work but as Marlon mentioned that it requires customization. Thanks. Considered as the answer.